# Slick way to calculate $\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T(\sin(t+1)-1)^4\,dt$ by hand?

Tags: integration

An electrical engineering friend in an introductory signals and systems class asked me for advice on calculating

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T(\sin(t+1)-1)^4\,dt$$

by hand. I don't see a better way to do this than writing $\sin(t+1)$ using complex exponentials and then doing the binomial expansion. Is there a slicker approach?

Comment: It's the average value of $(\sin(t+1)-1)^4$ over some interval.  Does that help?

Comment: If it is the mean value of the integrand over $\mathbb R$, and it's periodic, this integral reduces down to a small interval.

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{35}{8}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: I got that from Mathematica. But how to get this by hand without a bunch of busy work?

Comment: For me, the fastest way would be to take my above hints to turn the sine into cosine, then binomial expand, then reduce using Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.

Comment: i have spent some ours with that problem

Comment: it is a good Training for human to find that limit

Comment: You could try using L'hopital's rule in conjunction with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I don't see what you mean about switching to a cosine. Can you write up the approach?

Comment: @user170231 That limit has to exist for us to use L'H.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the integrand is periodic, hence:

$$I=\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T(\sin(t+1)-1)^4\ dt=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin(t+1)-1)^4\ dt\\I=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi(\cos(t)+1)^4\ dt$$

Binomial expanding and [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html):

$$\begin{align}8(c(t)+1)^4&=8c^4(t)+32c^3(t)+48c^2(t)+32c(t)+8\\&=c(4t)+8c(3t)+28c(2t)+56c(t)+35\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}8\pi I&=\int_0^\pi c(4t)+8c(3t)+28c(2t)+56c(t)+35\ dt\\&=\frac14s(4t)+\frac83s(3t)+14s(2t)+56s(t)+35t\bigg|_{t=0}^\pi\\&=35\pi\end{align}$$

Thus,

> $$I=\frac{35}8$$

Comment: We might be able to answer this by letting $t \to 2t$ and then using the power reduction formula for $\cos^2(x)$ in reverse. I'll check out this route later. Should remove the need for binomial expansion if done right. Regardless, good answer: a +1 from me

Comment: Thanks, this is slick. I'm having a bit of trouble, though, proving rigorously that we can replace the original problem with the average value over a period. Here is the obvious first step. Consider $F(T):=\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^Tf(x)\,dx$ where $f$ is periodic with period $P$. Setting $T=nP/2$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ gives $F(nP/2)=\frac{1}{nP}\cdot n\int_{-P/2}^{P/2}f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{P}\int_{-P/2}^{P/2}f$. So as $n\to\infty$, $F(nP/2)$ converges to (in fact, is always equal to) the average over a period. *But in general $g(x_n)\to L$ as $x_n\to\infty$ does not imply $g(x)\to L$ as $x\to\infty$.*

Comment: (Continued) How do we repair or finish this argument to get the conclusion?

Comment: @symplectomorphic Hint:$$\int_{-T}^Tf(x)\ dx=\int_{2\pi-T}^Tf(x)\ dx+\underbrace{\int_T^{2\pi}f(x)\ dx}_{Bounded?}$$

Comment: @symplectomorphic Er, the right most integral should have $T+2\pi$ as the upper bound.

Answer (score 3):

It is clear we can transform our integral into
$$I=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi(\cos(t)+1)^4\ dt$$
See @SimplyBeautifulArt's answer for a proof. Once we are here we let $x \to 2x$
$$I=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos(2x)+1)^4\ dx$$
$$I=\frac{2^5}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^8(x)\ dx$$
By symmetry this is simply
$$I=\frac{2^3}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^8(x)\ dx$$
We now have a fairly standard integral, for which many clever solutions can be found. A fairly general one is to apply the common reduction formulas over repeatedly to find that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^n(x) dx = \frac{2\pi}{2^n}{n \choose n/2}$$
Applying this closed form here, we find that
$$I=\frac{1}{2^4}{8 \choose 4}= \frac{70}{16}=\frac{35}{8}$$
Of course, we could always use the fact that $\cos^2(x) = 1-\sin^2(x)$ to reduce the power of our integral, or substitute $u=\cos(x)$ or $u=\cos^8(x)$, or any other number of tricks to solve without resorting to the general closed form. I only use the general form because it is relatively well known. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125591/integral-of-cosnx-on-0-2-pi-for-n-a-positive-integer) for a few proofs.

Comment: Slick avoidance of the binomial expansion, +1.

Answer (score 0):

take the area of $ (sin(t)+1)^4$, over $2 \pi$, once you expand the $ (sin(t)+1)^4$, sine terms to the odd power give zero area.    so you have to find the area of $sin^4x + 6 Sin^2x+1$. It comes to $70\pi/8$. dividing it by $2\pi$, gives $35/8$.