# Finding a polynomial for this trigonometric equality

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

For all natural numbers, find the polynomials such that $$\cos(n\theta)=p_n(\tan(\theta))\cos^n(\theta)$$
It was suggested that taking $p_n(x)=\frac{1}{2}\{(1+ix)^n+(1-ix)^n\}$, but I don't know how?

Comment: Maybe this is of help to you: [Power-reduction formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/125539/19341)...

Comment: Since I teach some maths, students come and ask strage questions like this. Some question can be soft but some of them like this one is not.

Comment: That formula is wrong, but it is right that $\cos(n\theta)=p_n(\tan(\theta))\cos^n(\theta)$.  The difference is that $\tan(\theta)$ rather than $\tan(n\theta)$

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/125814/19341) for an example with [$n=10$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/125774/19341).

Comment: @draks: What wonderful relations they are, I didn't know them before.

Comment: @BabakSorouh you're welcome.

Comment: It's probably closely related to [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Comment: @draks: Do you think this one can be completely carried out by what you had linked here for me, or we can use induction on $n$?

Comment: @BabakSorouh I'm not sure, but the answer below solves it very nice...

Comment: @draks Just a stylistic recommendation.  When you create a link, always include some non-math in the link code, so that people can right click on the link and open it in a new tab if they want to.  Unfortunately, when you right click in MathJax code, it only pops of the MathJax menu.  So, above, you should link to "example with $n=10$" rather than just the text "$n=10"$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the hint, I tend to use the middle mouse click so I never realized it.

Comment: There is even a meta post on that topic: [MathJax menu obliterates link menu when the entire link is LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1204/19341).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $q_n(x) = (1+ix)^n$.

Then $$q_n(\tan(\theta))\cos^n(\theta) = (1+i\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos \theta})^n\cos^n\theta = (\cos \theta + i\sin\theta)^n = \cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta$$

So $p_n(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(q_n(x)+q_n(-x)\right)$

Use that $\cos(-x)=\cos x$ to show that

$$p_n(\tan\theta)\cos^n\theta = \cos n\theta $$

Comment: Dear Thomas, I edited the question as others and you noted, but how could I guess this polynomial. Guessing is a bit hard. :)

Comment: Well, the general guideline is that if you want to associate polynomials about trig functions in $\theta$ with some trig function on $n\theta$ is that the fundamental such formula is:$$(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)^n = \cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$$

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the answer and hint.