# An other tricky one. Tigonometric integral.

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How should I attack this ?
$$ \int_0^{\pi} \cos(ax)^m \cos(x)^n dx$$

Comment: Are $n$ and $m$ assumed to be integers or are they any real numbers?

Comment: both $n, m$ are positive integers. $a$ is a real constant.

Comment: Is this from a class/textbook? What methods have you been learning that might relate? Or what methods are in that section of the book? (As an added note, [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int_0^{\pi}+\cos%285x%29^m+\cos%28x%29^n+dx) was unable to compute this integral so I doubt it's going to have a simple answer).

Comment: No its not from any textbooks. The power reduction formula seems to be the way to go. Here is the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125539/power-reduction-formula. Express $\cos(ax)^m$ as a binomial series of $\cos(ax(m-k))$. You are right it seems like a mess.

Comment: The result seems to be zero for any $m \neq n$ if $a$ is an integer?