# Trigonometric Power Formulas (or something more modest)

Tags: trigonometry, exponentiation, harmonic-analysis, orthogonality

How does one begin to show (natural $n$):
$$\cos^{2n}(x) =\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n}+ \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n}{k} \cos[2(n-k)x]$$
$$\cos^{2n+1}(x) =\frac{1}{4^{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{k} \cos[(2n + 1 - 2k)x]$$

Alternately, how can I prove that that the l.h.s of the second is a linear combinations of all $\cos{kx}$, where $k$ are the odd  $k \leq 2n+1$?

This leads to the intriguing fact that $cos^m{x}$ is orthogonal to $\cos nx$ for all $m < n$..

Comment: Induction, perhaps?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar perhaps.. I'll try. Thanks. Doesn't look induction friendly :-)

Comment: True. However, seeing $\cos^{2n}(x),\cos^{2n+1}(x)$ made induction the first thing to come to my mind.

Comment: The case of 2n is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125539/power-reduction-formula?rq=1