# How to prove that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 e^{\cos \theta}\,d\theta = \sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(n!2^n)^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> How to prove that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 e^{\cos \theta}\,d\theta = \sum\limits^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(n!2^n)^2}.$$

It seems Laurent expansion doesn't work well here. I visited similar questions, maybe expand $1=\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)$ or some different arguments? Still not working to me.

Comment: Did you try with Bessel function?

Comment: I would use the substitution $u=\cos\theta$ and use Integration by Parts

Comment: expand $e^{\cos\theta}$ as $\sum \cos^n\theta/n!$ and integrate termwise.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Crap my brain jams recently. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taylor series of $$e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
For $$x = \cos \theta$$

$$e^{\cos \theta} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^n\theta}{n!}$$
Let's integrate
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos \theta} \ d \theta = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi n!}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^n\theta \ d\theta$$

But for even $n$ we have: $$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^n \theta = \frac{2 \pi}{2^{2k}}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}$$
and zero for odd $n$ ([See here why](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125539/power-reduction-formula)), 
Therefore:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos \theta} \ d \theta = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi (2k)!}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi (2k)!}\frac{2 \pi}{2^{2k}}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2k}}\frac{(1}{(k!)^2} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2^k k!)^2}$$

Comment: Very detailed. Thank you.

Comment: @MonkeyKing welcome !!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** With [Bessel's integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel's_integrals) form and also series form
$$J_0(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ix\sin\tau}\ d\tau=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{(k!)^2}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{2k}$$
set $x=i$ and you will find the result. Also modified Bessel functions $I_0(x)$ has the same case.