# How to integrate Elliptic function with gaussian kernel

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I have an integral problem as follows:
$$
I(k,\sigma)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+k^2\sin^2(x)}}dx,
$$
where $k,\sigma>0$.
The function to be integrated is an elliptic function multiplied by a Gaussian kernel. I searched from Google and have no solution. Maybe one possible approach is first to find the power series of the elliptic function:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2\sin^2(x)}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(k)x^n.
$$
However, this is not easy too.

Comment: Assuming $|k|<1$$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2\sin^2(x)}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}k^{2n}\sin(x)^{2n}$$ hence you just have to compute $$ I_n = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\sin(x)^{2n}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,dx$$

Comment: First, thank you so much. I have tried your idea. According to the [Power-reduction formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125539/power-reduction-formula), one can get the result of $I_n$ with the form of infinite series summation. Finally, $I(k,\sigma)$ could be written as a summation of multiple infinite series. Is it possible to simplify the result further?